# Unable to compile TypeScript: Cannot find module 'fs'

Tags: typescript, mocha.js

I get error

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
>   server/src/test/test.ts(2,45): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'

When I run this test

```
import "mocha"
import { writeFileSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import migrator from '../utils/Migrator';
import {expect} from "chai"

describe("cleanTimestamp",()=>{
    it("should round to nearest seconds",()=>{
        // migrator.start()
       const ans =  migrator.cleanTimestamp(('(1558312599408)'))
      expect(ans).equal(1558298199000);
    });
})
```

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74617912/tserror-%e2%a8%af-unable-to-compile-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used webstorm. My project root directory does not have `node_modules` folder. My `node_modules` foler is actually inside subdirectory `server/` . So when I click on run test, webstorm search for the node_modules in the root directory. To solve this, I changed the root directory to `server/`

[image]